# copying 14gb file from ftp to azure data lake store using ADF

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy 14gb file from FTP to my azure data lake store using Azure data factory. When I executed the pipeline it started copying the file and copied almost 13.9 gb within half hour.

Remaining data is not copied even after running the pipeline for 8 hours and finally failed by providing message that file not available. Reason for file not available is the source team removed the file for next file.

Increased the integration unit to 250

```
{
    "name": "job_fa",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "set_parameters_adh_or_sch",
                "description": "validate and set the parameter values based on the runtype sch or adh",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "br_bs_loggin",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [
                    {
                        "name": "CheckLookup1",
                        "value": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "SqlSource",
                        "sqlReaderStoredProcedureName": "[dbo].[usp_FeedParameters_main]",
                        "storedProcedureParameters": {
                            "FeedName_in": {
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.p_FeedName",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            },
                            "RunType_in": {
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.p_RunType",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            },
                            "SrcEnddate_in": {
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.p_SrcEndDate",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            },
                            "SrcStartdate_in": {
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.p_SrcStartDate",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            },
                            "TgtDate_in": {
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.p_TargetDate",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            },
                            "SrcHour_in": {
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.p_SrcHour",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            },
                            "TgtHour_in": {
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.p_TgtHour",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSql_cdpconfiguser",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": true
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "br_bs_loggin",
                "description": "insert into the batch run and update the batch scheduler to started in case of sch run",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "SqlSource",
                        "sqlReaderStoredProcedureName": "[dbo].[usp_BatchRun]",
                        "storedProcedureParameters": {
                            "FeedName_in": {
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.p_FeedName",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            },
                            "RunType_in": {
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.p_RunType",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            },
                            "Status_in": {
                                "type": "String",
                                "value": "Started"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSql_cdpconfiguser",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": true
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Check if file exists in target",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Copy Data WT to ADLS",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureDataLakeStoreFile_wt_tgt_path_and_name",
                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "TgtFilePath": "@activity('set_parameters_adh_or_sch').output.firstrow.TgtFileName_wt_dt_out",
                            "TgtFileName": {
                                "value": "@activity('set_parameters_adh_or_sch').output.firstrow.TgtFileName_wt_dt_out",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "exists",
                        "size"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Copy Data WT to ADLS",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "set_parameters_adh_or_sch",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [
                    {
                        "name": "Source",
                        "value": "@{activity('set_parameters_adh_or_sch').output.firstrow.SrcFilePath_wo_dt_out}/@{activity('set_parameters_adh_or_sch').output.firstrow.SrcFileName_wt_dt_out}"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Destination",
                        "value": "@{activity('set_parameters_adh_or_sch').output.firstrow.TgtFilePath_wt_dt_out}/@{activity('set_parameters_adh_or_sch').output.firstrow.TgtFilePath_wt_dt_out}"
                    }
                ],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "FileSystemSource",
                        "recursive": true
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreSink"
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "dataIntegrationUnits": 0
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "FTP_SRC_FA",
                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "SrcFileName": "@activity('set_parameters_adh_or_sch').output.firstrow.SrcFileName_wt_dt_out",
                            "SrcFilePath": "@activity('set_parameters_adh_or_sch').output.firstrow.SrcFilePath_wo_dt_out"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "AzureDataLakeStoreFile_wt_tgt_path_and_name",
                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "TgtFilePath": "@activity('set_parameters_adh_or_sch').output.firstrow.TgtFileName_wt_dt_out",
                            "TgtFileName": {
                                "value": "@activity('set_parameters_adh_or_sch').output.firstrow.TgtFileName_wt_dt_out",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "br_bs_update_failed",
                "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Copy Data WT to ADLS",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Failed"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[usp_BatchRunUpdate]",
                    "storedProcedureParameters": {
                        "BatchId": {
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@activity('br_bs_loggin').output.firstrow.Batchid_out",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "type": "String"
                        },
                        "FeedID": {
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@activity('br_bs_loggin').output.firstrow.FeedId_out",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "type": "Int32"
                        },
                        "FeedRunId": {
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@activity('br_bs_loggin').output.firstrow.BatchRunId_out",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "type": "Int32"
                        },
                        "Status": {
                            "value": "Failed",
                            "type": "String"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlDatabase1_cdp_dev_sql_db_appconfig",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "If Condition1",
                "type": "IfCondition",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Check if file exists in target",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@equals(activity('Check if file exists in target').output.Exists,true)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "ifFalseActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Stored Procedure_failed",
                            "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[usp_BatchRunUpdate]",
                                "storedProcedureParameters": {
                                    "BatchId": {
                                        "value": {
                                            "value": "@activity('br_bs_loggin').output.firstrow.Batchid_out",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "type": "String"
                                    },
                                    "FeedID": {
                                        "value": {
                                            "value": "@activity('br_bs_loggin').output.firstrow.FeedId_out",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "type": "Int32"
                                    },
                                    "FeedRunId": {
                                        "value": {
                                            "value": "@activity('br_bs_loggin').output.firstrow.BatchRunId_out",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "type": "Int32"
                                    },
                                    "Status": {
                                        "value": "Failed",
                                        "type": "String"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "linkedServiceName": {
                                "referenceName": "AzureSqlDatabase1_cdp_dev_sql_db_appconfig",
                                "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "ifTrueActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Stored Procedure1",
                            "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[usp_BatchRunUpdate]",
                                "storedProcedureParameters": {
                                    "BatchId": {
                                        "value": {
                                            "value": "@activity('br_bs_loggin').output.firstrow.Batchid_out",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "type": "String"
                                    },
                                    "FeedID": {
                                        "value": {
                                            "value": "@activity('br_bs_loggin').output.firstrow.FeedId_out",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "type": "Int32"
                                    },
                                    "FeedRunId": {
                                        "value": {
                                            "value": "@activity('br_bs_loggin').output.firstrow.BatchRunId_out",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "type": "Int32"
                                    },
                                    "Status": {
                                        "value": "Succeeded",
                                        "type": "String"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "linkedServiceName": {
                                "referenceName": "AzureSqlDatabase1_cdp_dev_sql_db_appconfig",
                                "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "p_FeedName": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "fa_cpsmyid_vdumcap1"
            },
            "p_BatchType": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "RAW"
            },
            "p_RunType": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "sch"
            },
            "p_SrcStartDate": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "p_SrcEndDate": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "p_TargetDate": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "p_SrcHour": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "p_TgtHour": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "v_StartDate": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "v_EndDate": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "folder": {
            "name": "Batch_load"
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

Comment: Hi,if you think my answer helps you,could you mark it for answer?Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description,all concern is about improving transfer performance,i think.

Firstly,referring to the [Data integration units statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#data-integration-units), `DIU` only applies to [Azure Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#azure-integration-runtime), but not [Self-hosted Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#self-hosted-integration-runtime).Your source data is from FTP,so i think it is not affected by the `DIU` even though you already set the largest number.(Of course,it is referred by the official document,you still could get the verification from ADF team)

Then maybe you could get some clues to improve the copy performance from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance).

Such as:
1. Try to use the `parallelCopies` property to indicate the parallelism that you want Copy Activity to use. But it also has some restrictions from the [statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#parallel-copy).

2.Try to set the sink dataset as `Azure SQL Data Warehouse`,because it seems that it has better performance than ADL.

[image]

3.Try to compression the file from the source dataset to reduce the file size.

4.Consider to use Azure Cloud Service as source dataset such as Azure Blob Storage,as i know, the performance of copy activity between azure services is better commonly.